# How to handle consumer thread interruption in a synchronous queue?

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I have a use case where I synchronize data with another service which performs long polling via HTTP.

For that purpose, I use a `SynchronousQueue` which works perfectly except that when I receive a poll from the consuming service, I call `take` on the queue, but the remote service may die, causing the thread associated to the HTTP request to stay alive without eventually returning any HTTP response. Still, the `take` method would eventually return in that thread and consume the data which would then be lost.

How do I handle this problem?

Comment: A `SynchronousQueue` doesn’t know anything about the thread that is not calling `offer`. But if you have exactly one consumer waiting for exactly one producer, why do they even communicate via a `SynchronousQueue`? It would make more sense to have a `Future` or something similar. Or just not to use two different threads when one would perform a blocking wait for the other anyway.

Comment: I have two different threads (a NIO thread on the consumer, and a Quartz thread on the producer) so I can't have just one thread. You suggest to use a `Future` can you elaborate because I don't see how it would solve my problem. I need the producer to block until a consumer takes the message

Comment: Why do you want to block the producer?

Comment: Because I want it to be aware of the success or error. Callbacks may also be suitable I guess

Comment: @Holger if you have any idea of a pattern that would be suitable for me, I'd be glad to know it

Comment: I don’t know enough about your case. Maybe, `CompletableFuture` can help. If you can express your different thread contexts as `Executor`s, you can chain subsequent actions (callbacks) using the various `then…Async(functionOrAction, executor)` methods.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if there are better solutions (would love to know), but I'm sharing mine:

### Service

```
private record ContentAndFile(LongPollingDto dto, File file) {
}

private Queue<CompletableFuture<LongPollingDto>> consumers = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
private Queue<ContentAndFile> messages = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

public CompletableFuture<LongPollingDto> getFutureDto() throws IOException {
    CompletableFuture<LongPollingDto> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    consumers.add(future);
    match();

    return future;
}

public void enqueue(LongPollingDto content) throws IOException {
    String uniqueFileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".json";
    File file = new File(syncTmpDataDirectory, uniqueFileName);
    writer.writeValue(file, content);
    doEnqueue(content, file);
    match();
}

@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
protected void synchronizeTemporaryFiles() throws IOException {
    File tmpDir = new File(syncTmpDataDirectory);

    List<File> files = Arrays.asList(tmpDir.listFiles());
    files.sort(Comparator.comparing(File::lastModified));

    files.forEach(x -> {
        try {
            LongPollingDto dto = mapper.readValue(x, LongPollingDto.class);
            doEnqueue(dto, x);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error when syncing file: {}", x.getAbsolutePath(), e);
        }
    });

    match();
}

private void match() throws IOException {
    if (!consumers.isEmpty() && !messages.isEmpty()) {
        CompletableFuture<LongPollingDto> future = consumers.poll();
        if (!future.isCancelled()) {
            ContentAndFile contentAndFile = messages.poll();
            future.complete(contentAndFile.dto);
            Files.delete(contentAndFile.file.toPath());
        }

        match();
    }
}

private void doEnqueue(LongPollingDto dto, File file) {
    messages.add(new ContentAndFile(dto, file));
}
```

### Controller

```
@GetMapping("long-polling")
public DeferredResult<LongPollingDto> longPolling() throws IOException {

    DeferredResult<LongPollingDto> result = new DeferredResult<>();

    CompletableFuture<LongPollingDto> futureDto = longPollingService.getFutureDto();

    executor.execute(() -> {
        try {
            result.setResult(futureDto.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            log.error("An error occurred when transferring the file: ", e);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            log.debug("The CompletableFuture has been cancelled. Probable cause: the listener has disconnected.");
        }
    });

    result.onCompletion(() -> futureDto.cancel(true));

    return result;
}
```

This solution allows me to have multiple parallel consumers that perform long-polling, and it allows to cleanup the consumer (to avoid data loss) when the client has died. It also persists messages on the disk to avoid data loss if my application goes down.